# SwaggerUI through Swashbuckle documenting two different models against 1 ASP.NET WEB API action

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have a scenario where my ASP.NET WEB API returns 2 different models depending upon the request object. I am using swagger UI (through swashbuckle) to document my ASP.NET WEB API and currently is unable to find a way to document these 2 models against 1 ASP.NET WEB API action.
I have tried googling but was not fruitful. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of your action?

Comment: It looks like what you need to use is ***SwaggerResponse*** but is hard to know for sure without a sample code...    ```[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of customers", typeof(IEnumerable<int>))]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenAPI (formerly known as Swagger) specification version 2 does not have any way of describing two different models for the same operation.  With the new OpenAPI V3 you can use a schema with the `oneOf` attribute to describe multiple possible response shapes.

However, there isn't much tooling available yet for V3.

Comment: Darrel Miller, I do have same opinion but I was not sure. Thank you for making me sure :)